# Get byte[] from int in c++

Tags: c++

So in my C++ program I am trying to replicate the C# `BitConverter.GetBytes()` function, or at least find some method in which it will return same result, (btw I cannot use `std::vector<unsigned char>` which I've seen a few people recommend on other forums).

I'm using this so I can take an `int` and then get a `byte[]` of it then take that `byte[]` and use it to set memory at a particular memory address. I've also tried

```
int x;
static_cast<char*>(static_cast<void*>(&x));
```

with no luck. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Which version of C++ are you using that doesn't have `std::vector`?

Comment: @doctorlove It's for the PS3 console using PS3 SDK, compile errors occur when trying to include <vector>

Comment: I hate to say that but `reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x);` is one way to do this. Avoid this casting if you can.

Comment: You can't use 'char".  In c# 'char' is a class with two bytes and a private property which indicates if a character is one or two bytes.  You must use byte[] in c#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <string>

int i = 123;
char c[sizeof(int)];
std::memcpy(c,&i,sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Since it's C++, you'd better prefer C++ functions such as `std::fill` and `std::copy`.

Comment: @black, I don't think `std::copy` is good idea for memory copy. but `memcpy`, or in terms of C++ `std::memcpy` is. `std::memcpy is the fastest library routine for memory-to-memory copy` - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy#Notes. I've updated my answer to make it clear

Comment: The byte order (little endian / big endian) - as does the `sizeof(int)` - depends on the processor. But one could test whether int 1 reaches c[0].

Comment: @folibis: It's not about performance (often, they're wrappers around them). It's about readability and type safety that `std::copy` can give unlike `memcpy`.

Comment: @black, can you please provide you solution with `std::copy`?

Comment: @folibis: solution for what?

Answer (score 0):

Another method would be

```
union Value
{
   int val;
   char bytearray[sizeof(int)];
};
```

which does not use memcpy.Instead it allows a value in memory as different types